# How to force OAuth2 to get data from Youtube API

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth

I want to use OAuth2 login and I also need to view Youtube data.
How can I force the check box to be checked?
Thanks!

My PHP login code:

```
$google_client = new Google_Client();
//auth
$google_client->setClientId(ClientID);
$google_client->setClientSecret(SecretKey);

$google_client->setRedirectUri('https://example.com');
$google_client->setAccessType('offline');
$google_client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$google_client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$google_client->addScope(array(
    'email', 'profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
));
```

It is always [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnl6G.png) when the user tries to login for the first time.

Comment: You cant the user has the option to select if they want to allow it or not

Comment: Mind taking a picture of the screen you are talking about.  It seems others don't understand your question.

Comment: @DaImTo it's in the post https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnl6G.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The checkboxes are due to the rolling out of granular account permission system, they are completely normal, and can not be turned off.

[More granular Google Account permissions with Google OAuth and APIs](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/more-granular-google-account.html)

Comment: Interesting enough after the first login, the second time users logs in, the youtube access is forced